# Queue shapes must have the same length as dtypes

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Im trying to initialize a FIFOQueue similar to the shape of my numpy array
but get the below error.

My - numpy array shape - (1, 17428, 3)

```
dtypes=[tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.float32]
print len(dtypes)
shapes=[1, 17428, 3]
print len(shapes)
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=200,dtypes=dtypes,shapes=shapes)

ValueError: Queue shapes must have the same length as dtypes
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQueue) specifies that the parameters for `FIFOQueue`'s constructor are (emphasis mine):

> - `dtypes`: A list of `DType` objects. The length of `dtypes` must equal the number of tensors in each queue element.
> - `shapes`: (Optional.) A list of **fully-defined `TensorShape` objects** with the same length as `dtypes`, or `None`.

What you are specifying as `shapes` is not a list of fully-defined `TensorShape` objects, though. It is a list of three dimensions that will be interpreted as one `TensorShape` resulting in `shapes=[TensorShape([Dimension(1), Dimension(17428), Dimension(3)])]` which is of length 1. To tell the constructor that you want three 1D tensors you can specify:

```
shapes=[tf.TensorShape(1), tf.TensorShape(17428), tf.TensorShape(3)]
```

Then `q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=200,dtypes=dtypes,shapes=shapes)` will run and no error will be raised.